mock motor AsyncIOMotorClient with uuid settings
I have AsyncIOMotorClient code as below.
def get_client():
    """
    Get Client.

    Get the client for the database connection.
    """
    return motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient(
        os.getenv(
            "DB_CONN_STR",
            "mongodb://user:pass@127.0.0.1:27017"
        ),
        uuidRepresentation='standard',
    )

in this, I am setting uuidRepresentation='standard' to make sure UUID will parse properly.
I use mongomock-motor and mock the client as below.
from mongomock_motor import AsyncMongoMockClient

class MockSession():
    client = AsyncMongoMockClient(
        uuidRepresentation='standard',
    )

def override_get_session():
    return MockSession()


app.dependency_overrides[get_session] = override_get_session

When I run testcase where it need UUID, it fail with below error.
app_client = <starlette.testclient.TestClient object at 0x10344a9d0>

    def test_valid_payload(app_client):
        payload = {
            "country": "ARE",
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "first_name": "TEst",
            "last_name": "Surname",
            "password": "PAssword@123",
            "phone": "+911234567890"
        }
>       response = app_client.post("/doctor/signup", json=payload)

tests/integration/doctor/test_post_signup.py:123:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/testclient.py:597: in post
    return super().post(
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_client.py:1144: in post
    return self.request(
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/testclient.py:488: in request
    return super().request(
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_client.py:825: in request
    return self.send(request, auth=auth, follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_client.py:914: in send
    response = self._send_handling_auth(
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_client.py:942: in _send_handling_auth
    response = self._send_handling_redirects(
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_client.py:979: in _send_handling_redirects
    response = self._send_single_request(request)
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_client.py:1014: in _send_single_request
    response = transport.handle_request(request)
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/testclient.py:381: in handle_request
    raise exc
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/testclient.py:378: in handle_request
    portal.call(self.app, scope, receive, send)
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/from_thread.py:290: in call
    return cast(T_Retval, self.start_task_soon(func, *args).result())
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/_base.py:456: in result
    return self.__get_result()
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/_base.py:401: in __get_result
    raise self._exception
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/from_thread.py:221: in _call_func
    retval = await retval_or_awaitable
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py:1054: in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/applications.py:113: in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py:187: in __call__
    raise exc
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py:165: in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py:62: in __call__
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(self.app, conn)(scope, receive, send)
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py:62: in wrapped_app
    raise exc
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py:51: in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py:715: in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py:735: in app
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py:288: in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py:76: in app
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(app, request)(scope, receive, send)
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py:62: in wrapped_app
    raise exc
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py:51: in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py:73: in app
    response = await f(request)
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py:301: in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py:212: in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
src/noveraapi/routers/doctor.py:64: in create_doctor
    new_doctor = await collection.insert_one(
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mongomock_motor/__init__.py:43: in wrapper
    return getattr(proxy_source, method_name)(*args, **kwargs)
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mongomock/collection.py:497: in insert_one
    return InsertOneResult(self._insert(document, session), acknowledged=True)
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mongomock_motor/patches.py:58: in wrapper
    return fn(data, *args, **kwargs)
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mongomock/collection.py:552: in _insert
    BSON.encode(data, check_keys=check_keys)
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bson/__init__.py:1429: in encode
    return cls(encode(document, check_keys, codec_options))
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bson/__init__.py:1050: in encode
    return _dict_to_bson(document, check_keys, codec_options)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

cls = <class 'bson.binary.Binary'>, uuid = UUID('097cb7d0-1b2a-43a5-8686-a3525615d254'), uuid_representation = 0

    @classmethod
    def from_uuid(
        cls: Type[Binary], uuid: UUID, uuid_representation: int = UuidRepresentation.STANDARD
    ) -> Binary:
        """Create a BSON Binary object from a Python UUID.

        Creates a :class:`~bson.binary.Binary` object from a
        :class:`uuid.UUID` instance. Assumes that the native
        :class:`uuid.UUID` instance uses the byte-order implied by the
        provided ``uuid_representation``.

        Raises :exc:`TypeError` if `uuid` is not an instance of
        :class:`~uuid.UUID`.

        :param uuid: A :class:`uuid.UUID` instance.
        :param uuid_representation: A member of
            :class:`~bson.binary.UuidRepresentation`. Default:
            :const:`~bson.binary.UuidRepresentation.STANDARD`.
            See :ref:`handling-uuid-data-example` for details.

        .. versionadded:: 3.11
        """
        if not isinstance(uuid, UUID):
            raise TypeError("uuid must be an instance of uuid.UUID")

        if uuid_representation not in ALL_UUID_REPRESENTATIONS:
            raise ValueError(
                "uuid_representation must be a value from bson.binary.UuidRepresentation"
            )

        if uuid_representation == UuidRepresentation.UNSPECIFIED:
>           raise ValueError(
                "cannot encode native uuid.UUID with "
                "UuidRepresentation.UNSPECIFIED. UUIDs can be manually "
                "converted to bson.Binary instances using "
                "bson.Binary.from_uuid() or a different UuidRepresentation "
                "can be configured. See the documentation for "
                "UuidRepresentation for more information."
            )
E           ValueError: cannot encode native uuid.UUID with UuidRepresentation.UNSPECIFIED. UUIDs can be manually converted to bson.Binary instances using bson.Binary.from_uuid() or a different UuidRepresentation can be configured. See the documentation for UuidRepresentation for more information.

venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bson/binary.py:272: ValueError

how to make uuidRepresentation working in mock client ?
